# Measuring latency between tasks in C#

Tags: c#, performance, stopwatch

I am aware of an currently using the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class, but since I am measuring latency, I would like to know if the stopwatch is really the correct tool for the job.

Is it accurate enough? How reliable are the results?

Comment: How accurate do you need to be?

Comment: I'd say unless you need to meet some specific time-measurement for a method - you would be better off using a profiling tool to find performance issues.

Comment: @blins I would like nanosecond measurements, but can live with milliseconds.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates that it might not be reliable on a multiprocessor mach: On a multiprocessor computer, it does not matter which processor the thread runs on. However, because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL), you can get different timing results on different processors.

Comment: I second @Allan S. Hansen's remark... For instance, Visual Studio has has some decent performance tools already baked-in. Also, I imagine the variance you would measure from test run to test run will far out weigh any amount of error introduced by (speculated) inaccuracies of `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

> "Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
>   accurately measure elapsed time."

From what I've read - it is the recommended way, and exactly the thing it's been created for (in terms of accuracy)

It's recommended to use it, instead of DateTime.Now - someValueInThePast, or other approaches with timers or similar